# Does one need to know BNF grammar in order to learn flex and Bison?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

Does one need to learn BNF grammar or text processing algo in order to learn 
Flex and Bison or similar kind of parsers/scanners?

I am planning to learn flex and Bison but I haven't got any compiler writing 
level knowledge so please tell me if it is possible to learn flex and Bison 
without knowing BNF grammar and without having compiler writing level knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Let us say that you will learn BNF grammar and text-processing algorithms as a by-product of learning Flex and Bison.  If you happen to have learned BNF academically, then your prior study will help you, but such prior study probably is not necessary to your purpose.

Incidentally, if your language happens to be C++, then the usual, modern tool that fills Bison's old role is [Boost Spirit.](http://boost-spirit.com/)

Comment: Thanks. Is it absolute necessary to follow BNF and text processing algo beside flex and bison? Though I can't understand what you've meant by by-product of flex and byson but I feel quite free now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know it before you start using these tools, you will know it afterwards. Grammars go hand-in-hand with these tools so this gives you the opportunity to learn both.

If you want a textbook on the subject, I recommend [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745144). However it covers many other subjects and is overall a good reference for implementing languages.

My tool of choice rather than Flex/Bison is [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/). It is a very popular, modern, and easy  to use tool. It has great documentation as well as a few books to reference. Here is a screenshot of the editor:
[image: ANTLR]

Comment: This is going to be a great help. Thank you very much. :)